# Angulars JS: call webmethod in aspx Forms Authentication

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs

I know I search the problems...lol

I need to call a webmethod define in login.aspx who is authentification forms.But it doesn't work (I use IIS in localhost)

Web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"></forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

JS:

```
$scope.CheckIdentification = function (user) {
    $http({ method: typeRquestP, url: window.location.href + '/test', contentType: contentType_, dataType: dtp })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.test = data.d;
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        });
};
```

Webmethod in aspx:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string test()
{
   return "Great!";
}
```

I need your help.
Thanks per advance

Comment: What sort of response are you getting on your call? 500/404?

Comment: I have no error :/

Comment: Well your http call should be returning a 200 if successful. Are you saying you're not sure what sort of response you are getting?

Comment: I am verify in console and i have error 401:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: Well ya, `<deny users="?"/>` is denying you access to that method. Change it to `<allow users="*"/>` as all users should have access to the login method.

Comment: It's better. Thank you.